# How to run single line SQL for all blogs on multisite

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a multisite and need to run a few SQLs sometimes. But I can't figure out how to in a single line run this command but for **all** sites. There are more than 50 of them so 50 lines feels kind of lame to do.

```
UPDATE wp_1_posts SET comment_status = 'open';
UPDATE wp_2_posts SET comment_status = 'open';
UPDATE wp_3_posts SET comment_status = 'open';
UPDATE wp_4_posts SET comment_status = 'open';
UPDATE wp_5_posts SET comment_status = 'open';
```

Is there a way like this to change on **all** blogs:

```
UPDATE wp_*_posts SET comment_status = 'open';
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not write wrap it in a for loop in php and then use variables for the names and only write it in once?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query :

```
DECLARE @sqlCommand nvarchar(max)
declare @index int 
set @index=1
while 1 = 1
    BEGIN
        SET @sqlCommand = 'update wp_'+CAST(@index as nvarchar(10))+'_posts 
        set comment_status=''open''' 
        EXECUTE sp_executesql @sqlCommand
        if @index =50 BREAK
        set @index =@index +1 
    END
```